# Examining Convergence Of Improper Integral.

Tags: improper-integrals

I have to check the convergence of the improper integral $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos^2x\,dx .$$

I have tried to solve it in the following manner:
$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos^2x\,dx &= \lim_{B \to \infty} \int_{0}^{B}\cos^2x\,dx \\&=  \lim_{B \to \infty} \int_{0}^{B}(1-\sin^2(x))\,dx \\ &=   \lim_{B \to \infty}[x]_{0}^{B} -\lim_{B \to \infty} \int_{0}^{B}\sin^2(x)\,dx .\end{align}$$

Now the first term tends to infinity as $B \to \infty,$ so the integral is not convergent.

But unfortunately the answer is given to be convergent. I don't understand how ?

Also I have proven in the same way that $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} (\sin x^2)^2\,dx $$ is divergent. So basically I think that if my process is wrong then I am wrong in both cases.

Am I wrong ? If so, looking for guidance then.
Thank you.

Comment: You cannot do this this way: the first term goes to $+\infty$, but if the second goes to $-\infty$ you have an indeterminate form.

Comment: Oh ! I see. Then what way should I prefer ?

Comment: What you *could* do, however, is observe that $\cos^2 x$ is periodic with period $\pi$, and $\int_T^{T+\pi} \cos^2 x dx = \frac{\pi}{2}>0$. So...

Comment: No, it diverges. See my answer.

Comment: Yes.. I was mistaken, sorry I put down my comment as I didn't notice your answer.

Comment: @ hiren_garai Perhaps there is a typo in your text and the $^2$ is meant to stand under the $\cos$. Then we have  $\int_0^{\infty } \cos \left(x^2\right) \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}$

Comment: yes, that might have happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot proceed this way, as you end up with something of the form
$$
\int_0^B dx\, \cos^2 x = u_B - v_B
$$
and $\lim_{B\to\infty} u_B = \infty$. But if $\lim_{B\to\infty} v_B = \infty$ as well, you have an indeterminate form and cannot conclude.

---

However, note that $\cos^2$ is perdiodic with period $\pi$, so that for any integer $k$
$$
\int_0^{k\pi} dx\, \cos^2 x = k\int_0^\pi dx\, \cos^2 x = k\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}
$$
and therefore
$$
\int_0^{B} dx\, \cos^2 x = \int_0^{\lfloor B/\pi\rfloor \pi} dx\, \cos^2 x
+ \underbrace{\int_{\lfloor B/\pi\rfloor \pi}^B dx\, \cos^2 x}_{\geq 0} \geq  \lfloor B/\pi\rfloor\cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \xrightarrow[B\to\infty]{} \infty
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In a similar way I can prove the divergence of $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \text{(sin x²)² dx} $$, right ?

Comment: @hiren_garai yes, indeed.

Comment: I have one more query, can I visualise the problem in the way that it is the integration of a positive term from $0$ to $\infty$ and so the area of the curve will be unbounded and hence the integral is divergent ? It's just to find a rough idea about the problem . @ClementC.

Comment: Of course, one may write $$\int_0^L \cos^2(x)\,dx=\frac12 L+\frac14 \sin(2L) $$and conclude.

Comment: I got it.@MarkViola. thanks for your time.

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks for the comment (and indeed, once can just write the explicit close-form integral, as you point out). The periodic "trick" is helpful in general, but not necessary here.

Comment: Hi Clement!  It's always nice to see you on MSE.  And indeed, the periodic "trick" has broad application.  (+1)